# Spring boot with mysql and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I want to learn how spring boot can be used with MySql using Hibernate and JPA.
I want some simple, easy to understand source in order to learn this.
I browsed and found some github repos but that did not help me to understand.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started with this a while ago and couldn't find a good tutorial, either but have you looked into the direct documentation of Spring, especially here:

An explanation how to work with Spring Boot and SQL Databases:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

The JPA Reference Documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: I am going through these documentations. Still if you find any helpful examples then pls provide materail

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Samples on GitHub:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa

Getting started guides:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
- https://spring.io/guides

And docs:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.
I will go through these stuff. Can you provide me links for spring data jpa also?

Comment: What links do you mean? Links above also covers basics for Spring Data JPA. But if you want more details you can start here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/ in section 'Related Resources - Sample Projects'.